# Latch generation warning in Verilog 8-bit processor code

Tags: verilog, xilinx-ise

I have encountered this warning while synthesizing my 8-bit MIPS processor Verilog code in Xilinx ISE.

> Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <6>>. Latches may be
>   generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend
>   the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing
>   problems.

What should I do to solve this? (as I'm new to Xilinx and making my first assignment on it).

This is the code :

```
{ module execution_unit(ld,write,enable_alu,en_Memory,addr,indata,outdata,fn_sel,flag_register);

input ld,write,enable_alu,en_Memory;

input [7:0] indata;                                             //Input data

wire [7:0] Databus;                                             //Databus

input [2:0] addr;                               //Address bus

reg [7:0] mem_value;

output reg [3:0] flag_register = 0;

reg [8:0] output9bit=0;                         //Holds the 9-bit output of some operations like add,subtract

output [7:0] outdata;

reg [7:0] Memory [0:5];                     //Registers

input [2:0] fn_sel;                     //Function select lines

assign outdata = mem_value;

assign Databus = ld ? indata : mem_value;   //When ld = 1, load input data in databus. Else, when ld = 0, load databus with value which has been read



//Data Memory

always @(*)

begin

if (en_Memory)

    begin

        if (write) 

        Memory [addr] = Databus;    // Write

        else 

        mem_value = Memory [addr];      // Read

    end



//ALU

if(enable_alu)

begin

case(fn_sel)

    3'b000: begin               //add

            output9bit = Memory [0]+Memory [1];

            Memory [0] = output9bit [7:0];              //R0 is standard output register

            flag_register [3] = output9bit [8];

            if (Memory [0] == 8'b00000000)

            flag_register [0] = 1; 

            else 

            flag_register [0] = 0;

            end

    3'b001: begin               //subtract

            output9bit  = Memory [0]-Memory [1];

            Memory [0] = output9bit [7:0];

            flag_register [3] = output9bit [8]; 

            if (Memory [0] == 8'b00000000)

            flag_register [0] = 1;

            else 

            flag_register [0] = 0;

            end

    3'b010: begin               //and

             Memory [0] = Memory [0]& Memory [1];

             if (Memory [0] == 8'b00000000)

             flag_register [0] = 1;

             else 

             flag_register [0] = 0;

             end

    3'b011: begin               //or

             Memory [0] = Memory [0]|Memory [1];

             if (Memory [0] == 8'b00000000)

             flag_register [0] = 1;

             else 

             flag_register [0] = 0;

             end

    3'b100: begin               //left shift

             flag_register [2] = Memory [0] [7];    //bit shifted out

             Memory [0] = Memory [0]<<1;

             if (Memory [0] == 8'b00000000)

             flag_register [0] = 1;

             else 

             flag_register [0] = 0;

             end

    3'b101: begin               //right shift

             flag_register [2] = Memory [0] [0];

             Memory [0] = Memory [0]>>1;

             if (Memory [0] == 8'b00000000)

             flag_register [0] = 1;

             else 

             flag_register [0] = 0;

             end

    3'b110: begin               //compare 

             output9bit  = Memory [1]-Memory [0];

             flag_register [1] = output9bit [8];            //Becomes 1 when Memory[0] > Memory[1]

             if (output9bit == 9'b000000000)

             flag_register [0] = 1;

             else 

             flag_register [0] = 0;

             end

    3'b111: begin               //increment

             output9bit = Memory [0] + 1;

             flag_register [3] = output9bit [8];

             Memory [0] = output9bit [7:0];

             if (Memory [0] == 0)

             flag_register [0] = 1;

             else

             flag_register [0] = 0;

             end

endcase

end 

end



endmodule

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Instruction Decoder

module instruction_decoder(instructions,op1,op2,op3,data,opcode,ram_address);

input [30:0] instructions;

output [2:0] op1,op2,op3;

output [7:0] data;

output [3:0] opcode;

output [9:0] ram_address;

assign ram_address = instructions [30:21];

assign data = instructions [20:13];

assign op1 = instructions [12:10];

assign op2 = instructions [9:7];

assign op3 = instructions [6:4];

assign opcode = instructions [3:0];

endmodule



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Execution Unit Control Logic

module eucl(clock,op1,op2,op3,data,opcode,dataout,p_c,output_pc,en_ram,wram,str,load_ram);

input [7:0] p_c;                                            //Input value of PC

input [2:0] op1,op2,op3;                                    //Operands

input [3:0] opcode;

output [7:0] output_pc;                                     //Output value of PC

input [7:0] data;

wire [3:0] flag;

output reg en_ram,wram,str,load_ram;

reg [7:0] branch;

reg p_c_val,check_branch; 

input clock;

output [7:0] dataout;

reg ld,write,enable_alu,en_Memory;

reg [2:0] addr;                                         

reg [2:0] control_bus;

reg [4:0] state = 5'b00000;                                 //State machine

assign output_pc = check_branch ? branch : p_c + p_c_val;           

initial 

begin 

branch=0;

p_c_val = 0;

check_branch=0;

load_ram=0;

str=0;

ld=0;

write=0;

enable_alu=0;

en_Memory=0;

wram=0;

en_ram=0;

end

execution_unit EU(.ld(ld),.write(write),.enable_alu(enable_alu),.en_Memory(en_Memory),.addr(addr),.indata(data),.outdata(dataout),.fn_sel(control_bus),.flag_register(flag));



always @(posedge clock)

begin



check_branch <=0;

ld<=0;

write<=0;

enable_alu<=0;

en_Memory <=0;

p_c_val<=0;

wram <= 0;

en_ram <= 0;

branch <= data;

load_ram <= 0;

str <= 0;



if (state==5'b01111) //Increments value of program counter 

begin

state<=5'b00000;    //Reset to zero state

p_c_val<=1;

end 



else if (state==5'b11111) //Branching

begin

check_branch <= 1;

state <= 5'b00000;

end



else if(opcode==4'b0001) // move from op1 to op2

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;                                         //Memory is enabled for read

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=op2;

en_Memory <= 1;                 

write <= 1;                                         

state <= 5'b01111;                                      //Increment PC

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b0010) //load to memory

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

ld <= 1;                //Load memory

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b0011) //add

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;                                  //Write op1 to R0

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

addr <= op2;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00011;

end 

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <=3'b001;                                  //Write op2 to R1

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b000;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b00101;

end

else if (state==5'b00101)

begin

addr <= 3'b000 ;                                //Read the value stored in R0(the standard output register)

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00110;

end

else if (state==5'b00110)

begin

addr <= op3;                                    //Write value of R0 to op3

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b0100) //subtract

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

addr <= op2;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00011;

end 

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <=3'b001;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b001;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b00101;

end

else if (state==5'b00101)

begin

addr <= 3'b000 ;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00110;

end

else if (state==5'b00110)

begin

addr <= op3;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b0101) //and

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

addr <= op2;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00011;

end 

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <=3'b001;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b010;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b00101;

end

else if (state==5'b00101)

begin

addr <= 3'b000 ;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00110;

end

else if (state==5'b00110)

begin

addr <= op3;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b0110) //or

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

addr <= op2;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00011;

end 

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <=3'b001;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b011;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b00101;

end

else if (state==5'b00101)

begin

addr <= 3'b000 ;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00110;

end

else if (state==5'b00110)

begin

addr <= op3;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b0111) //left shift

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b100;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b00011;

end

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <= 3'b000 ;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1000) //right shift

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b101;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b00011;

end

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <= 3'b000 ;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1001) //store in RAM from memory

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

en_ram <= 1;

wram <= 1;

str <= 1;                           //data_out

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1010) //compare flag set if op1 > op2

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

addr <= op1;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00001;

end 

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

addr <=3'b000;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00010;

end

else if (state==5'b00010)

begin

addr <= op2;

en_Memory <= 1;

state <= 5'b00011;

end 

else if (state==5'b00011)

begin

addr <=3'b001;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;

state <= 5'b00100;

end

else if (state==5'b00100)

begin

control_bus <= 3'b110;

enable_alu <= 1 ;

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1011) //Branch if greater

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

if (flag [1])

state <= 5'b11111;                          //Branch

else

state <= 5'b01111;                          //Don't branch

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1100) //Branch if zero

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

if (flag [0])

state <= 5'b11111;

else

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1101) //Branch if shifted out bit 

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

if (flag [2])

state <= 5'b11111;

else

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1110) //load to Memory from RAM

begin

if (state==5'b00000)

begin

en_ram <= 1;

load_ram <= 1;                          //Read from RAM         

state <= 5'b00001;

end

else if (state==5'b00001)

begin

load_ram <= 1;

addr <= op1;

ld <= 1;

en_Memory <= 1;

write <= 1;                         //Write to memory

state <= 5'b01111;

end

end



else if (opcode==4'b1111) //Load to RAM immediate

begin

en_ram <= 1;

wram <= 1;

state <= 5'b01111;

end



end

endmodule

//Program Memory

module program_Memory(p_c,instr);

input [7:0] p_c;                                //Line of program

reg [30:0] p_memory [0:255];                    //Program memory

output [30:0] instr;

initial begin

//Add

p_memory [0] = 31'b0000000000000001100100000000010; //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [1] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010; //Load 8. op1 = 100

p_memory [2] = 31'b0000000000000000001000100100011;  //Add 100 and 010. Store in 010.

//Sub

p_memory [3] = 31'b0000000000000001100100000000010; //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [4] = 31'b0000000000000001001000000000010; //Load 4. op1 = 100

p_memory [5] = 31'b0000000000000000000101000100100;  //Subtract 010 - 100. Store in 010.

//And

p_memory [6] = 31'b0000000000000001010100000000010; //Load 5. op1 = 010

p_memory [7] = 31'b0000000000000000111000000000010; //Load 3. op1 = 100

p_memory [8] = 31'b0000000000000000000101000100101;  //And both. Store in 010.

//Or

p_memory [9] = 31'b0000000000000001100100000000010; //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [10] = 31'b0000000000000000111000000000010;    //Load 3. op1 = 100

p_memory [11] = 31'b0000000000000000000101000100110;  //Or both. Store in 010.

//Left shift

p_memory [12] = 31'b0000000000011001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [13] = 31'b0000000000000000000100000000111;    //Logical shift left

//Right shift

p_memory [14] = 31'b0000000000011001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [15] = 31'b0000000000000000000100000001000;    //Logical shift right

//Compare         

p_memory [16] = 31'b0000000000000001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010 

p_memory [17] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010;    //Load 8. op1 = 100        

p_memory [18] = 31'b0000000000000000000101000001010;    //compare    

//Branch if greater         

p_memory [19] = 31'b0000000000000001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010 

p_memory [20] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010;    //Load 8. op1 = 100         

p_memory [21] = 31'b0000000000000000000010000001011;           

//Branch if zero         

p_memory [22] = 31'b0000000000011001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [23] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010;    //Load 8. op1 = 100          

p_memory [24] = 31'b0000000000000000000010000001100;            

//Branch if a bit is shifted out         

p_memory [25] = 31'b0000000000011001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010

p_memory [26] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010;    //Load 8. op1 = 100          

p_memory [27] = 31'b0000000000000000000010000001101;            

//Load from Memory         

p_memory [28] = 31'b0000000000011001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010 

p_memory [29] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010;    //Load 8. op1 = 100         

p_memory [30] = 31'b0000000000000000000010000001110;             

//Load Memory (RAM) immediate         

p_memory [31] = 31'b0000000000011001100100000000010;    //Load 6. op1 = 010 

p_memory [32] = 31'b0000000000000010001000000000010;    //Load 8. op1 = 100         

p_memory [33] = 31'b0000000000000000000010000001111;             

end         

assign instr = p_memory [p_c];         

endmodule



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Main Memory (RAM)

module main_Memory (enable, Write, Address, Databus, DataOut);

    input Write,enable;

    input [7: 0] Databus;

    input [9: 0] Address;           //10-bit address

    output reg [7: 0] DataOut;

    reg [7: 0] Memory [0: 1023];    // 1024 x 8 Memory

    always @ (*)

    begin

    if (enable)

    begin

        if (Write) 

        Memory [Address] <= Databus;    // Write

        else 

        DataOut <= Memory [Address];    //Read

    end

    end

endmodule



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Control Unit

module control_unit(clock,data_out,temp);

input clock;

wire [9:0] ram_ad;

reg [7:0] p_c = 0;

wire [7:0] pfcl,data,ram_out,ram_in,data_eucl;

wire [2:0] op1,op2,op3;

wire [3:0] opcode;

wire [30:0] instr;

wire en_ram,ram_w,str,load_ram;

output [7:0] data_out,temp;

assign ram_in = str ? data_out : data;          //store vs load immediate

assign data_eucl = load_ram ? ram_out : data;   //load immediate reg vs load  

program_Memory PM(.p_c(pfcl),.instr(instr));

instruction_decoder IDE(.instructions(instr),.op1(op1),.op2(op2),.op3(op3),.data(data),.opcode(opcode),.ram_address(ram_ad));

eucl EUCL(.clock(clock),.op1(op1),.op2(op2),.op3(op3),.data(data_eucl),.opcode(opcode),.dataout(data_out),.p_c(p_c),.output_pc(pfcl),.en_ram(en_ram),.wram(ram_w),.str(str),.load_ram(load_ram));

main_Memory RAM(.enable(en_ram),.Write(ram_w),.Address(ram_ad),.Databus(ram_in),.DataOut(ram_out));

always @(posedge clock)

begin

    p_c <= pfcl;

    end
    endmodule 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code in Vivado, there are several design issues that cause latch inference.

**1)** The memories need a clock. You should move the following parts into clocked `always` blocks.

The data memory:

```
if (en_Memory)
    begin
        if (write) 
            Memory [addr] = Databus;    // Write
        else 
            mem_value = Memory [addr];      // Read
    end
```

The main memory:

```
if (enable)
    begin
        if (Write) 
            Memory [Address] <= Databus;    // Write
        else 
            DataOut <= Memory [Address];    //Read
    end
```

**2)** The ALU part doesn't have complete assignments for all branches, so some latches are inferred here as well. You can assign default values at the top of the `always` block.

For example, `output9bit` and `flag_register` will be `0` for the missing branches:

```
always @(*) begin
    output9bit    = 0;
    flag_register = 0;
    // ALU
    if (enable_alu)
        ...
end
```

In addition, I see that you want `Memory` to be a register island rather than a RAM, that is why you can read multiple slots concurrently. If `Memory` is supposed to be something like a collection of accumulators, that is fine. ISE or Vivado should be able to map them correctly.

```
output9bit = Memory[0] + Memory[1];
```

Comment: I have done as you have mentioned but it is giving a warning saying 'signal p-memory unconnected in block program_memeory,tied to its initial value' I'm not getting whats wrong there.

Comment: @MariumH I haven't analysed all warnings. That can be a different question.